# How to efficiently iterate for sum over data.frame objects in the grid?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have numeric data.frame object in the list and want to add them parallel. However, I observe that adding paired data.frame object in the grid were repeated and I can only iterate over the upper/below triangle of grid and do sum over them parallel. I wrote simple R function for doing this, but my output bit of less efficient because repeated sum happens. I bet there must be more intuitive/efficient way for doing this job. Does anyone have better solution for doing this more easily/efficiently when data.frame objects are in grid? Any suggestion to better formulate my function for this task? Thanks

## simulated data

```
fo <- data.frame( start=seq(1, by=4, len=6), stop=seq(3, by=4, len=6))
ba <- data.frame(start=seq(5, by=2, len=7), stop=seq(7, by=2, len=7))
bleh <- data.frame(start=seq(1, by=5, len=5), stop=seq(3, by=5, len=5))

mylist <- list(fo, ba, bleh)
```

## my custom function

```
add_pairDF <- function(set, idx=1L) {
  quer <- set[[idx]]
  .quer <- mapply('+', quer, quer)
  supp <- lapply(set[-idx], function(ele_) {
    ans <- mapply('+', quer, ele_)
  })
  res <- c(list(.quer), supp)
  return(res)
}
```

## initial output (repetition exist):

```
ans_1 <- add_pairDF(set=mylist, idx=1L)
ans_2 <- add_pairDF(set=mylist, idx=2L)
ans_3 <- add_pairDF(set=mylist, idx=3L)
```

## desired output:

In my initial output, function does sum over paired data.frame object, but I think I don't need to hit my function three time with different index for mylist.

I want to remove repeated sum over paired data.frame, aim to walk on the below/upper triangle (including diagonal) if all paired data.frame object were placed in the grid square. How can I avoid this sort of repetition? what's the efficient iteration for data.frame object in the grid?Can anyone propose possible ideas to solve my problem?

Comment: Running your code as it is produces warnings because the data frames are of different lengths. Can you post the actual numeric output you're expecting and explain the purpose of this calculation?

Comment: you can ignore the warning for the time being. If you run my custom function three times like I showed in the post, it will be in grid pattern, doing this is not desired because of repeated sum happens. I am seeking more efficient iteration that only walk on the upper/below triangle of grid (including diagonal). Any better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way below.

```
add_df <- function(df1, df2) {
   mapply("+", df1, df2)
}

# Get all pairs of indices
ndf <- length(mylist)
idx <- expand.grid(1:ndf, 1:ndf)
idx <- idx[idx[,1] <= idx[,2],] 

Map(function(i, j) add_df(mylist[[i]], mylist[[j]]), idx[,1], idx[,2] )
```

I'm not sure what the intention is when adding data frames with different number of rows. But let's say you want the answer to only add the rows that both data frames have in common, you can replace `add_df` with:

```
add_df <- function(df1, df2) {
   nr <- min(nrow(df1), nrow(df2))
   df1[1:nr,] + df2[1:nr,]
}
```

EDIT: I replaced `mapply` with `Map` to make sure the result is a list in the latter case.